# Google Beacons nearby invalid url

Tags: google-nearby, google-beacon-platform

I configured a couple of beacons with iBeacon and Eddystone, filled all the data and added Nearby notifications for simple URL.

The problem is that only works for a kind of whitelist URLs: For example, with links for Google main page, Facebook, Microsoft or Yahoo (I don't put the complete link with "https://" because there is a limit of links I can add to this post) it works perfectly, but if I tried to add a places link (from Google places) an own domain, or even the same domain of the project package, the notification for that URL is not shown (and yes, all of them have the https).

Anyone else faced this problem? I read all doc, and watch Google videos, and the always use https://google.com as the demo URL. And there is no documentation about how do they do the URL filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's URL filtering is pretty simple:

1. The URL must resolve with a proper HTTP response code when fetched from Google's servers.  If the URL returns a 404 or other error code, that be shown.
2. The site must not have a robots.txt file at the root of the domain or subdomain that prohibits crawling the resource at the URL.
3. If it the URL scheme is HTTPS, the certificate must be valid.

If you have a URL that doesn't work for you and you believe meets all of the above criteria, you might add it to your question.

Comment: I think that these both should work: 

1. https://localistico.com

2. https://plus.google.com/_/widget/render/localreview?placeid=13984139533697957792

Comment: localistico.com does not have valid https cert, that's why it does not work.

Comment: https://plus.google.com/_/widget/render/localreview?placeid=13984139533697957792

returned 404.

They must be valid https sites with crawable content and valid certificate

Comment: Good point about the cert, that is required, too.  I have updated my answer.